# Optimize query performance in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection named `App` and need to query those active (`active: true`) apps that belong to a particular user (`user_id`) or are available to all users (by their `_id`). I use query like this

```
{
    "active" : true,
    "$or" : [
        {
            "user_id" : "111111111111111111111111"
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "$in" : [
                    ObjectId("222222222222222222222222"),
                    ObjectId("333333333333333333333333"),
                    ObjectId("444444444444444444444444")
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However in `db.currentOp(true)` I see that this query is running very slowly: `lockStats.timeLockedMicros.r` is about `3000`.
How can I optimize performance of this query? I already have the following indexes on `App`:

```
> db.App.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "mydb.App"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "active" : 1,
            "created_at" : -1
        },
        "name" : "active_1_created_at_-1",
        "ns" : "mydb.App",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "active" : 1,
            "user_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "active_1_user_id_1",
        "ns" : "mydb.App",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

Comment: FIrst step when debugging index usage is to call explain. Do that and update your question with the data. Are you doing any writes while running the query?

Comment: While I completely agree w/ Martin, putting a *boolean* at the first position in your query is nonsense in any case, as is indexing a boolean: It can only have two values, so it has only one bit of selectivity. This will unbalance your tree and might require a longish index scan. I'm not sure how smart mongo is about this, but putting the bool at the end, usually even after range queries, and removing it from the index shouln't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues I see here:

1) You would not need index on the boolean field `active` as it would have low selectivity and not benefiting query performance.

"If overall selectivity is low, and if MongoDB must read a number of documents to return results, then some queries may perform faster without indexes." [source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/)

2) You need an index for `user_id` because `user_id` cannot use the compound index you created for `active_1_user_id_1`

Edit: You can always check index efficiency by doing a `explain(true)` and look at which indexes are used for that query.

Comment: Following your advice I've been able to reduce number of scanned objects (viewed via `explain`) from about 1200 to 13! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do the following:

- remove all your indexes, your `active` field has a low cardinality (boolean) and does not help you at all, you are not using `created_at`, so there is no reason for it.
- add an index only on `user_id` key
- change your strings as numbers to numbers.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain "change your strings as numbers to numbers"?

Comment: @xaxa you have the following `"user_id" : "111111111111111111111111"`, therefore most probably in your application you save numbers as strings. Not only this is bad for comparison, it also increase the size of your indices.